# Tensorflow TypeError: Cannot convert 1e-12 to EagerTensor of dtype int32

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, tensorflow, tensor

I have a multiclass classification machine learning application for which I want to calculate the f1 score using tensorflow. The predicted and actual values are stored in pandas dataframes `y_pred` and `y_act` respectively. Both are populated with 1's and 0's. So I do something like this:

```
# convert dataframes to numpy
pred_numpy = numpy.asarray([y_pred], numpy.int32)
act_numpy = numpy.asarray([y_act], numpy.int32)

# compute multiclass f1
metric = tfa.metrics.F1Score(num_classes=num_classes, average="macro")
metric.update_state(act_numpy, pred_numpy)
print(metric.result().numpy())
```

However I get the following error

`TypeError: Cannot convert 1e-12 to EagerTensor of dtype int32`

There must be something with the type casting from pandas to tensorflow which is throwing the error. I have tried a series of mitigations to no avail.

I tried converting the numpy arrays to tensors like so:
`pred_tf = tf.convert_to_tensor(pred_numpy, numpy.int32)`

I tried ensuring the pandas dataframe has no 1e-12 instances with:
`y_pred = y_pred.replace(1e-12, 0)`

I tried converting to numpy without the `numpy.int32` option.

However I still get the same error. Any tips for converting from pandas to tensors successfully without getting this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the code sample provided on the tfa api docs:

```
metric = tfa.metrics.F1Score(num_classes=3, threshold=0.5)
y_true = np.array([[1, 1, 1],
                   [1, 0, 0],
                   [1, 1, 0]], np.int32)
y_pred = np.array([[0.2, 0.6, 0.7],
                   [0.2, 0.6, 0.6],
                   [0.6, 0.8, 0.0]], np.float32)
metric.update_state(y_true, y_pred)
result = metric.result()
result.numpy()
```

Note that the `y_pred` array is the original outputs of the model and is `float`, likely from a softmax activation. If you look at the [code](https://github.com/tensorflow/addons/blob/45928da883eef6e512f99e6820c56c0b2d09ee3f/tensorflow_addons/metrics/f_scores.py#L143) for the function, this is supported as it performs an argmax along the final dimension, or thresholds the probabilities. Therefore, if you cast these to an `int`, the probabilities will all be truncated to `0`, although I suspect you're passing the already argmaxed values anyway.

I suspect this specific error comes from this line in the API:

```
y_pred = tf.logical_and(y_pred >= threshold, tf.abs(y_pred) > 1e-12)
```

as it can't compare the int32 you're providing with 1e-12 and tries to convert the second value.

Comment: Wow, that is not expected behavior from the tensorflow F1Score function. Great find on the API code. The updated and functional call looks like:

Comment: ```
# convert dataframes to numpy

pred_numpy = numpy.asarray([y_pred], numpy.int32)

act_numpy = numpy.asarray([y_act], numpy.float32)


# compute multiclass f1

metric = tfa.metrics.F1Score(num_classes=num_classes, average="macro", threshold=0.5)

metric.update_state(act_numpy, pred_numpy)

print(metric.result().numpy())

```

Comment: Hmm, adding code seems to be difficult in comments. Moral of the story just convert y_act to numpy.float32 and add a threshold=0.5 argument to the metric.